# Heroku error cant resolve: error Command "build" not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy my small full-stack app. The file structure is something like this. I am using a node server and client folder is created by create-react-app.

```
\MyApp
  \server.js
  \package.json
  \client
    \package.json
```

My outer package.json scripts look something like this:

```
 "scripts": {
   "client": "cd client && yarn start",
   "server": "nodemon server.js",
   "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn 
   client\"",
   "dev:server": "cd client && yarn build && cd .. && yarn start",
   "start": "node server.js",
   "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && yarn install && yarn install -- 
    only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && yarn run build"
  },
```

My Client package.json scripts look something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

But when I am trying to deploy my app on heroku it throws the following error:

```
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "build" not found.
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation  
 about this command.
 error Command failed with exit code 1.
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation 
 about this command.
 -----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common .   
   issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/

   Love,
   Heroku

   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
   !     Push failed
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: thank you for asking this question 

Answer (score 3):

I had a exactly same issue, and I tried to some ways to solve this problem. Finally I could find that it's because client folder is exists as submodule on my github repository. So I changed client as normal folder, and pushing to heroku worked. The steps I suggest to you:

1. check state of client folder on your github repository
2. if client folder is submodule (unclickable), follow the next steps

2-1. remove .git folder in client folder (`cd client` && `rm -rf .git`)

2-2. remove remote client folder cache (`git rm -r --cache client`)

2-3. add, commit and push to remote repository (`git add .` && `git commit` && `git push`). so change your client folder state

3. Finally push to heroku (`git push heroku master`)

I think may be heroku couldn't access and execute command to submodules. If this few steps works fine or not, please let me know.

Comment: OMG, you are a life saver, i was troubled for 2 days and finally got here,`git rm -r --cache client` did the job for me, thanks very much